# inverse matrix Python3 mpi4py EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, mpi4py

I'm writing a piece of code that will inverse a matrix with the use of `mpi4py`. I'm getting an error that's giving me issues.

I put 2 default variables `m, n` and the user inserts the numbers into the `rank 0` process to fill the matrix. The process `rank 0` sends the matrix  to the `process 1` and `process 2`. In `process 1` I initialize the matrix and the determinant, calculate the determinant, and send it back to `rank 0`. In `process 2`, I initialize the matrix, find the inverse matrix, and send back the inverse matrix to the process 0.

In `process 0` I then receive the determinant and the inverse matrix. If the determinant is 0, a message will be sent and the program will exit (the inverse matrix can be calculated even if the determinant is 0, but it's not correct). If it's not 0, the program will print the inverse matrix.

Note that I know the current implementation is not the best way to parallelize this problem, but I needed to start from somewhere.

The determinant was giving me some errors so I initialized it as an empty `numpy` array of 2 elements, where the first element is the determinant and the second is 0. I edited the code a bit from my native language to English so it could be read and understood easier, therefore it may contain some errors.

The problem is that when I want to give the user the privilege to write the matrix size. I checked some related answers, and have tried using `map()`, `raw_input()`, and other options, but none have worked.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
from scipy.linalg import det
from mpi4py import MPI



comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

m = int(input())
n = int(input())

if rank==0:
    matrix = np.zeros((m,n))
    determinant = np.zeros((2))
    for i in range (0,m):
        for j in range(0,n):
            print("Enter the value for the field: m = ", i+1, ", n = ", j+1,"\n")
            matrix[i][j] = float(input())

    comm.Send(matrix, dest=1, tag=0)
    comm.Send(matrix, dest=2, tag=0)
    comm.Recv(determinant, source=1, tag=0)
    comm.Recv(matrix, source=2, tag=0)
    if(determinant[0]==0):
        print("There is no inverse matrix since the determinant is 0!")
    else:
        print("Inverse matrix:\n",matrica)
elif rank==1:
    matrix = np.zeros((m,n))
    determinant = np.zeros((2))
    comm.Recv(matrix, source=0, tag=0)
    determinant = np.array([[det(matrix)],[0]])
    comm.Send(determinant, dest=0)
elif rank==2:
    matrix = np.zeros((m,n))
    comm.Recv(matrix, source=0, tag=0)
    matrix = inv(matrix)
    comm.Send(matrix, dest=0)
else:
    exit()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lambda.py", line 13, in <module>
    m = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lambda.py", line 13, in <module>
    m = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

EDIT:
I'm using PuTTY to connect to a Debian OS from the university.

Interpreter version: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

I enter the command line: mpirun -np 3 python3 lambda.py, I get an EoFError and insert the numbers till the point where it should do something, when instead of doing it, it continues to run as an infinite loop.(Better seen in the picture)
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s866j.png)

Added the code to trace the input:

```
m = int(input("Enter number of rows, m = \n"))
n = int(input("Enter number of columns, n = \n"))
```

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jirqb.png)

Comment: You mention that you've edited the code from your native language to English. Could you please test the revised code and confirm that it behaves the same as your native code? Otherwise it's pointless for us to troubleshoot it.

Comment: How are you actually executing the code? Are you sure it is Python3.

Comment: @MarcoBubi, could you please run the following in either your interpreter, or save it as a python file, run it, and tell us the result? It should tell us your interpreter's version: `import sys;print(sys.version_info)`

Comment: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

I'm using a putty to connect to the university's terminal, I'm sure it's python3, the coce I execute is : mpirun -np 3 python3 lambda.py, since lambda.py is the name of the file.

@ali_m there is no input since the error appears, if I set m = 3 and n = 3, than it works normally.

Comment: Execution should pause on that line until you type an input and hit return. What is happening in your case? You could make this behavior more obvious by adding a prompt string, e.g. `s = input("Enter the value for m: ")`.

Comment: @ali_m so, mostly it works like this...I input the element, let's say 3 and 3. It lets me write the 9 elements and after that nothing happens. I can write more inputs but it doesn't end.

Comment: That sounds like totally different behavior to the `EOFError` you described in your question. Could you update your question to clarify what's going on?

Comment: @ali_m I will describe all I do. Like this: I run the file with the command line, "mpirun -np 3 python3 lambda.py". I get the EOFError, I input 3 and 3. Then I enter the for loop and I write all 9 elements of the matrix, after that it looks like I enter in a endless loop where I can input any string, but the code won't end. Here is a screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/a68wzj

Comment: Could you add the details to your question rather than the comments? It makes it much easier for others to follow what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with matrices: it's that your line

```
m = int(input())
```

is happening on all nodes.  You need to do it on the root node and then share the results however you like, say with a broadcast.  For example, if we start with

```
from mpi4py import MPI

x = input("enter x: ")
```

we get

```
(3.5) dsm@winter:~/coding/mpipar$ mpirun -np 3 python m1.py
enter x: enter x: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m1.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = input("enter x: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
enter x: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m1.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = input("enter x: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

and note that there are two errors.  But if we protect it:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

x = None
if rank == 0:
    x = input("enter x: ")

x = comm.bcast(x, root=0)

print("rank", rank, "thinks x is", x)
```

then we get

```
(3.5) dsm@winter:~/coding/mpipar$ mpirun -np 3 python m2.py
enter x: abc
rank 0 thinks x is abc
rank 1 thinks x is abc
rank 2 thinks x is abc
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks! I knew it had to be done like that, just had no clue how, pretty new to python. Guess I need to check the docs a bit more. :P